# Linux, want to rotate oldest one files when it reaches limit

Tags: linux, rhel, logrotate

We have one Linux RHEL Machine where different log files are generating everyday with current date time under "/var/log/audit/" location.

File name are in below format:

```
audit_2021-11-24.trace
audit_2021-11-25.trace
audit_2021-11-26.trace
audit_2021-11-27.trace
audit_2021-11-28.trace
audit_2021-11-29.trace
```

I want to rotate the oldest file and delete that file once file count reach 5.
For this I configured the below file under "/etc/logrotate.d/" location

```
/var/log/audit/audit_*-*-*.trace {
    copytruncate
    dateext
    dateformat -%Y-%m-%d
    rotate 5
    ifempty
    missingok
    compress
}
```

But it's not working, this is rotating every file and not deleting the old file (which file are rotated).

Comment: A simple daily cron should do the trick. Something like: `find /var/log/audit/audit_* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: @MikeD thanks for the reply, can you please help me where I have to put this, in "/etc/logrotate.d/audit" file or somewhere else?

Comment: My suggestion is to put it in crontab. Here's some information on how it works: https://www.guru99.com/crontab-in-linux-with-examples.html